# Javascript image slider doesnt work

Tags: php

I get the "Table creation success" message but no table is created.

```
<html>
        <body>
        <?php

        $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

        //create db
        mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE VashDedomenwn2", $con);
        echo "Db creation success <br>";


        //create table
        $sql= mysql_query("CREATE TABLE VashDedomenwn2.phone_book
        (
        personID int NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(person ID),
        LastName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        FirstName varchar(20),
        Address varchar(30),
        Age int,
        Phone varchar(10)
        )
        ");

        mysql_query($sql,$con);
        echo "Table creation success <br>";

        //END CONNECTION
        mysql_close($con);
        ?>

        </body>
    </html>
```

I'm a newbie in php! Probably it's a stupid mistake... Thanks fot the help

Comment: you have not implemented any error detection or handling at all. So why/how do you expect to detect an error when calling `mysql_query()`? That call probably returns `FALSE` (why is irrelevant here), but you take it for granted that it succeeds and print out your success message. instead you have to check the return value and act accordingly!

Comment: Change `mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE VashDedomenwn2", $con);` to `mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE VashDedomenwn2", $con) or die(mysql_error());` and you will see whats the problem

Comment: I find it's easiest to write a database directly with phpMyAdmin, try it, you may like it.

Comment: You've tagged this with the phpMyAdmin tag, which is a graphical tool for managing databases, but are trying to run the SQL manually through your own PHP file. I'm a bit confused why you picked the phpmyadmin tag, then.

Answer (score 0):

Before you create a table, you must open the database you created.

```
//create db
mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE VashDedomenwn2", $con);
echo "Db creation success <br>";

mysql_select_db("database name", $con);

//create table
...
```

And change

```
$sql= mysql_query("CREATE TABLE VashDedomenwn2.phone_book
(
...
)
");
```

to

```
$sql= mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `VashDedomenwn2.phone_book`
(
...    
)
");
```

OK, as @php_purest said, use mysqli is better. Mysqli is the improved version of mysql which support OOPS. It can reduce the pressure of your server.

Like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","");

$conn->query("CREATE DATABASE VashDedomenwn2");
echo "Db creation success <br>";
$conn->select_db("VashDedomenwn2");

//create table
$conn->query("CREATE TABLE `VashDedomenwn2.phone_book`
(
personID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
LastName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(20),
Address varchar(30),
Age int,
Phone varchar(10)
)
");

echo "Table creation success <br>";

//END CONNECTION
$conn->close();
```

Comment: @php_purest He is a newbie, should start with the easy one

Comment: @php_purest but still need to know it

Comment: Correct your php, and I'll take away the negative point.  My point is that your answer will no longer be correct from beyond php 5.*  You can keep your answer, but also include either a PDO, or MySQLi answer, so your answer is just a partial answer.